# Best way to store uri in mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, facebook

I have an android app in which a user registers using his/her facebook account, and I want to get that user's profile picture, the method that the sdk offers returns the URI(i) for that profile picture, I want to send this uri to my php server and then store it in mysqldata base, and because I new to this I have a bunch of questions:
What is the best way (field) to store the uri in my server database?
I ll be doing in further steps some http request to download that picture, and the method I implemented to download a picture from a web server uses URLs, will I have issues in using the URI?
Is there other issues that I ll have to be aware of in using URIs?
Thank u in advance.

Comment: String.. you can convert uri to string and back

Answer (score 0):

As has been commented, the best way is to store it is in its `String` form.

You can store the `Uri` using the [toString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#toString()) method and when you get it back from your database later, you can use the [Uri.parse(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String)) method to get it back into a `Uri` object.

To answer your other questions...

> the method I implemented to download a picture from a web server uses
>   URLs, will I have issues in using the URI?

This shouldn't be a problem as it's a fairly simple task to convert from a `Uri` to a URL.

> Is there other issues that I ll have to be aware of in using URIs?

One thing to note is that Android has two types of Uri available in the SDK. The [one in the android.net package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) (the one I referred to above) and also [the one from the Java SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html). I would recommend you familiarise yourself with the available classes and decide which one is more suitable for your purposes.